# jQuery radio buttons not responding

Tags: jquery, html

When a user clicks the **Upload Prize** radio button, jQuery should show **#upload_prize_file_box input**. When a user clicks the **Provide Access** radio button, **pa_block** should be shown.

When I try to do that using the code below, the page doesn't respond.

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
 <td id="optBox">
    <input name="opt-radio" type="radio" id="upload_prize" value="upload_prize" checked="checked" />
    <label for="upload_prize">Upload Prize</label>
    <input name="opt-radio" type="radio" id="provide_access" value="provide_access" />
    <label for="provide_access">Provide Access</label>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="upload_prize_file_box" colspan="2" style="display:none;">
     <input type="file" name="upload_prize_file" id="upload_prize_file" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td height="160" colspan="2" id="pa_block" style="display:none;">
     <table width="100%" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="32%">URL</td>
       <td width="68%"><input type="text" name="pa_url" id="pa_url" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Username</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pa_username" id="pa_username" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pa_password" id="pa_password" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Is your prize attached to an affiliate program in Clickbank?</td>
       <td>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="pa_yes" value="pa_yes" />
            <label for="pa_yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="pa_no" value="pa_no" />
            <label for="pa_no">No</label>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea name="pa_textarea" id="pa_textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td height="29" colspan="2">Enter hoplink with our affiliate code, which is: iasst</td>
       </tr>
</table>
</td>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if("#optBox input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        if($("input[type=radio]:checked","optBox").val()=='upload_prize'){
            $("#upload_prize_file_box").show();
            $("#pa_block").css('display','none');
        }
        if($("input[type=radio]:checked","optBox").val()=='provide_access'){
            $("#pa_block").show();
            $("#upload_prize_file_box").css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GSXQ5/

How can I activate my radio buttons?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: What are we looking at? Can you just EDIT saying Expected behaviour, Current Behaviour?

Comment: I am trying when user click on **Upload Prize Radio button**, the jquery show **#upload_prize_file_box input**. and when user click on **Provide Access Radio button** then show **pa_block**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/GSXQ5/29/.

You missed the `<table>` tag, and the `$` symbol several times; in the second line of your jQuery code, you have typed `if` instead of `$`.

Comment: @RASG care to explain how you knew ahmed is the one who downvoted? It created [some fuss](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128074) in our Meta site. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure. i'll be there in few minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is invalid:  you have `td` and `tr` elements outside of a `table`.  Once you fix that:

```
$("#optBox input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    if(this.value == 'upload_prize'){
        $("#upload_prize_file_box").show();
        $("#pa_block").css('display','none');
    }  else if(this.value == 'provide_access'){
        $("#pa_block").show();
        $("#upload_prize_file_box").css('display','none');
    }
});
```

You were missing the `#` sign from your id selector: `$("input[type=radio]:checked","optBox")` should be `$("input[type=radio]:checked","#optBox")`.  You can use `this.value` to get the radio button value though, which is less verbose.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GSXQ5/23/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: still not working .. can you please try http://jsfiddle.net/GSXQ5/

Comment: thank you very much .. but can you please check this link .. http://www.contestsforhealth.com/sponsorship/ i am using here but here its not working .. but working in jsfiddle

Comment: Try using `jQuery` instead of `$` - it looks like the site is using `noConflict`to release the shortcut variable name.

Comment: i tried but still not responsding .. i think i should use noconflict

Comment: i tried .. `$j=jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 2):

`$("#optBox input[type=radio]").live('click',function(){`

.live attached a event handle to your radio button always. Try in your code.

Comment: i tried .. still not working :(

Comment: check the new Demo I have posted. Just write your functions inside the if conditions and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line of your javascript code you have placed `if` instead of `$`.

The line should have been:

```
$("#optBox input[type=radio]").click(function(){
```

Also you missed out `#` before `optBox` when checking if the radio is checked. Here, I have debugged the code for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#optBox input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        if($("input[type=radio]:checked","#optBox" /*You placed optBox instead of #optBox*/
            ).val()=='upload_prize'){
            $("#upload_prize_file_box").show();
            $("#pa_block").css('display','none');
        }
        if($("input[type=radio]:checked","#optBox" /*You placed optBox instead of #optBox*/
            ).val()=='provide_access'){
            $("#pa_block").show();
            $("#upload_prize_file_box").css('display','none');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Also I forgot to mention that your table doesn't follow correct markup. I have corrected it for you.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td id="optBox">
    <input name="opt-radio" type="radio" id="upload_prize" value="upload_prize" checked="checked" />
    <label for="upload_prize">Upload Prize</label>
    <input name="opt-radio" type="radio" id="provide_access" value="provide_access" />
    <label for="provide_access">Provide Access</label>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="upload_prize_file_box" colspan="2" style="display:none;">
     <input type="file" name="upload_prize_file" id="upload_prize_file" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td height="160" colspan="2" id="pa_block" style="display:none;">
     <table width="100%" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="32%">URL</td>
       <td width="68%"><input type="text" name="pa_url" id="pa_url" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Username</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pa_username" id="pa_username" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pa_password" id="pa_password" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Is your prize attached to an affiliate program in Clickbank?</td>
       <td>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="pa_yes" value="pa_yes" />
            <label for="pa_yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="pa_no" value="pa_no" />
            <label for="pa_no">No</label>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea name="pa_textarea" id="pa_textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td height="29" colspan="2">Enter hoplink with our affiliate code, which is: iasst</td>
       </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope that solves it.

Peace be upon you.

Comment: ohh, yes changed but still not working ... :(

Answer (score 1):

**first correct youre html**

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td id="optBox">
    <input name="opt-radio" type="radio" id="upload_prize" value="upload_prize" checked="checked" />
    <label for="upload_prize">Upload Prize</label>
    <input name="opt-radio" type="radio" id="provide_access" value="provide_access" />
    <label for="provide_access">Provide Access</label>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="upload_prize_file_box" colspan="2" style="display:none;">
     <input type="file" name="upload_prize_file" id="upload_prize_file" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td height="160" colspan="2" id="pa_block" style="display:none;">
     <table width="100%" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="32%">URL</td>
       <td width="68%"><input type="text" name="pa_url" id="pa_url" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Username</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pa_username" id="pa_username" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="pa_password" id="pa_password" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Is your prize attached to an affiliate program in Clickbank?</td>
       <td>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="pa_yes" value="pa_yes" />
            <label for="pa_yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="pa_no" value="pa_no" />
            <label for="pa_no">No</label>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea name="pa_textarea" id="pa_textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td height="29" colspan="2">Enter hoplink with our affiliate code, which is: iasst</td>
       </tr>
</table>
    </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input[name=opt-radio ]").click(function(){ 

        if( $(this).val() =='upload_prize'){
            $("#upload_prize_file_box").show();
            $("#pa_block").hide();
        } else if( $(this).val()=='provide_access'){
             $("#upload_prize_file_box").hide();
            $("#pa_block").hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually i am using here the codes.. http://www.contestsforhealth.com/sponsorship/ you can check. please take a moment to check

Comment: do you have jQuery running in WordPress? Maybe a conflict can happen with prototype.js Just a precaution.

Answer (score -1):

Check this working Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/GSXQ5/21/

### Edit

http://jsfiddle.net/GSXQ5/28/